# How Receive data from Label, while you have the name of that label in String

Tags: ios, objective-c, tags, nsstring, uilabel

I am new in IOS Dev, want to receive text data from one label among many labels, but i have just a name of label in String type variable.

```
NSString *tag = @"lbl_11"; 
NSString *recieved_label_data = tag.text;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't get what you want to know.

Comment: @trick14 i know how to save text data from UILabel ((( NSString *a = label.text ))) but i have that "label" in my another string type named "tag" but i cant do this : ((( NSString *recieved_label_data = tag.text; ))) so how can i save label data?

Comment: tag is already a type of NSString. What you just need to do is `NSString *recieved_label_data = tag`

Comment: Or `UILabel *tag = lal_11;` and `NSString *recieved_label_data = tag.text;`

Comment: see my UILabel name is in my string type variable ... yes tag is string that has the name of UILabel... and i want to receive text of that label

Comment: How are you creating the UILabel, in storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: @trick14 from storyboard

Comment: UILabel *lblTest = (UILabel *)NSClassFromString(@"tag");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the label is stored in a property, you could just use KVC. It can also find ivars in certain situations. Something like this:

```
UILabel *tagLabel = [self valueForKey:tag];
NSString *recieved_label_data = tagLabel.text;
```